# Possible to have a different iOS splash screen on first load?

Tags: ios, splash-screen

Would it be possible to show a different splash screen (launch image) on the first load of an application?

For example the first load would have a text ("Please wait while we setup your app..."), while the following loads would have another splash screen (no text for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not possible, since you can not change the launch image because the main bundle is read only.

You could however present a view controller just after your application is started and have the text in this view.
Just return as soon as possible from the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and only load the view controller with the text in this method.

Then start doing what ever your app need to do, and dismiss the view controller when done.

Answer (score 1):

No, the default image is there at a time when your app isn't yet executing any of your code (well mostly). The default screen is very quick to load on most modern devices, so instead of a splash screen, just use a normal view/view controller for setup.

Answer (score 0):

As both previous answer of *@nevan king* and *@rckoenes*, you can present a view controller and have the text or image or whatever in this custom splashscreen.

Add a method on `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to present this view :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // Create View Controller
    RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] init];

    // Create Navigation Controller
    self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // SplashScreen
    [self displaySplashscreen];

    return YES;
}
```

Create `displaySplashscreen`:

```
#pragma mark - SplashScreen Methods
- (void)displaySplashscreen
{
    // Create View
    self.splashscreenViewController = [[SplashscreenViewController alloc] init];

    // Display Splashscreen
    [_window addSubview:_splashscreenViewController.view];

    // Dismiss Splashscreen
    [self performSelector:@selector(dismissSplashscreen) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0f];
}
```

Create your `SplashscreenViewController` and build what you need in this view controller.